# LINQ to SQL multiple commits, how should I implement transactions?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions

I have the following two tables

Table 1:
PK (int)
TotalCount (int)

Table 2:
PK (int)
FK (int)(relation with PK in Table 1)
Count

I insert a record into the first table, in order to get a PK.  Then when I'm grabbing data from a source and dumping it into Table 2, I'm populating FK with the PK from the previous table.

I would like to implement transactions into my code.  How would I be able to roll back table 1 when inserting into table 2 fails, since table 1 is already issued a commit essentially?

I wrote a little code to help illustrate what I'm doing

```
using (DeviceDataContext context = new DeviceDataContext())
{
     tgdd = new Data();
     context.Datas.InsertOnSubmit(tgdd);
     context.SubmitChanges();

     int pk = tgdd.PK;

     int count = 0;
     foreach (…)
     {
          count += 1;
          tgd = new Data2();
          tgd.FK = pk;
          tgd.count = count;
          context.Datas2.InsertOnSubmit(tgd);  //if this crashes, I want to roll
                                               //back what happened to table 1(Datas)
     }

}
```

I wrote this code quickly, so if there's logical errors, please ignore.

So will transactions help me do what I want?

Comment: You should be able to wrap this in a TransactionScope.

Comment: Take a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx , there is a very useful example on how to use it (TransactionScope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you should have a navigation property on Data2 that you can set to your Data1 instance:

```
 tgdd = new Data();
 context.Datas.InsertOnSubmit(tgdd);

 int count = 0;
 foreach (…)
 {
      count += 1;
      tgd = new Data2();
      tgd.Tgdd = tgdd;
      tgd.count = count;
      context.Datas2.InsertOnSubmit(tgd);  //if this crashes, I want to roll
                                           //back what happened to table 1(Datas)
 }

 context.SubmitChanges();
```

That way this can not only be done in a single transaction scope, but also in a single database roundtrip.

If you can't do this using a navigation property, using a TransactionScope is the next-best thing.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your "using (DeviceDataContext context = new DeviceDataContext())" in a TransactionScope:

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
using (DeviceDataContext context = new DeviceDataContext())
{
   tgdd = new Data();
     context.Datas.InsertOnSubmit(tgdd);
     context.SubmitChanges();

     int pk = tgdd.PK;

     int count = 0;
     foreach (…)
     {
          count += 1;
          tgd = new Data2();
          tgd.FK = pk;
          tgd.count = count;
          context.Datas2.InsertOnSubmit(tgd);  //if this crashes, I want to roll
                                               //back what happened to table 1(Datas)
     }
   ts.Complete();
}
```

If the InsertOnSubmt fails, the transaction will automatically be rolledback.